# Using version_compare in Laravel 5.3 collection

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

So I have a collection that has a property with a version number as a string. I want to sort the collection on the version number.

I found this code online, but it takes a one dimensional array as the first argument.

`usort($a, 'version_compare');`

Any ideas on how accomplish this?

Maybe I could use pluck and sort with the above code, then use toArray() on the original collection and sort by the sorted array. I believe there is a function for that somewhere. But if any of you have another idea I will be happy to hear it.

Comment: Laravel collections have a `sort` function that accepts a closure. Should be pretty trivial to write a closure that compares based on `version_compare`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to set the sort method as the second argument. Like this:

```
$plugin->versions->sortBy('version', SORT_NATURAL)
```

This will do the trick :o)